# Applescript / Javascript unable to fill Safari input box

Tags: javascript, applescript

I have set my Safari homepage to a url that has a username and password form. My script should open Safari and set the username to a value. The script opens safari, the homepage is displayed, but no text added to input box.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell window 1
        delay 3
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('username').value = 'hello';"
    end tell
end tell

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="20" style="width: 150px;">
```

Can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell **Safari** where, e.g. `tab n of window n` or `document n`, etc.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('username').value = 'TheCoder';"
    end tell
end tell
```

**Or:**

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('username').value = 'TheCoder';" in document 1
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Neither put text in the input box.

Comment: Because provided by you HTML element doesn't contain **value** key. It should be other HTML element like this: **<input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit">**. Find similar HTML element and work with it>. To find, perform right click on the login text field and use Inspect Element.

Comment: @TheCoder, RE: "Neither put text in the input box." --  They did on the _input box_ I tested them on and without specifying `tab n of window n` or `document n`, which you didn't in your question, the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ would not work anyway. However, without being able to open to the exact **URL** so as to investigate the _source code_ on my own and test, then I submit that the issue is not in the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ of my answer but what you are targeting. The other comment has relevant info for you to troubleshoot your issue and then apply it as shown in my answer.

Comment: @user3439894 Your code worked when I added in a delay 3 before the javascript command was run. It seems the command was run before the html was rendered.

Comment: @TheCoder, It never fails... If I don't add my disclaimer, as I normally do, sure enough there is a `delay` _command_ issue.  So I've now added it after the fact. Glad you were able to get the _code_  to work for you.